# Is it possible to format the results of a query using a Lambda Expression?

Tags: c#, lambda, entity-framework-4.1

Let's say I have this query I pass to a repository:

```
var results = userRepository.Get(u => u.Username == "JDoe" && u.Password == "123456");
```

Now, let's say I create an expression to format the results a certain way:

```
Expression<Func<User,string>> userDisplay = u => u.Firstname + " " + u.LastName + " - " + u.CompanyName
```

So I may have to write my own extension, but something like this:

```
var formatedResults = results.Format(userDisplay);
```

**Update:**

What about a more complicated solution to project the results into another object:

```
public class SearchResult
{
     object EntityId {get; set;}
     object Displaytext {get; set;}

}
```

So, using the same idea to use the specific display expression, what is a good way to project the results into the SearchResult object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should be able to just call

**Update** As noted in the comments Select doesn't accept an Expression argument.  Unless `userDisplay` needs to be an expression it could just be updated as a delegate:

```
Func<User,string>> userDisplay = u => u.Firstname + " " + u.LastName + " - " + u.CompanyName;

var formatedResults = results.Select(userDisplay);
```

**Update**

Select allows you to transform whatever you are iterating over.

Some examples of what you could do:

```
var formattedResults = results.Select(x=> new SearchResult { EntityId = x.Id, DisplayText = userDisplay(x){);
//anonymous type
var formattedResults = results.Select(x=> new { EntityId = x.Id, DisplayText = x.ToString()});
```

Comment: Interesting....I never thought to use the Select method like this. didn't think it would work. I'll have to try it!

Comment: see my updated question regarding how to project the results while still using your select answer.

Comment: @Ken, this won't work, as `Select()` cannot take an `Expression<T>` as an argument. The expression would have to be `Compile()`d first.

Comment: @Frédéric, Thanks, I didn't even think to verify Select took Expression<T>.  In this case I personally would just use a normal delegate rather than an expression.

Comment: @DDiVita, I altered userDisplay to a function to match the method signature of Select; if you still have an expression you will need to compile it and invoke it with 'x' so you get a string.

Comment: I had thought it was still an expression<func>. I deleted my last comment.